# Ruby on Rails - render a collection within a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My user model has many projects, and each project has many invoices.

I am calling the following render

```
render :partial => "layouts/allInvoices", :collection => @projects, :as => :p
```

And inside the allInvoices, I wish to iterate over each project's invoices.

I can use

```
- p.invoices.each do |i|
```

But I'd rather use a collection.  I'm not sure how to phrase it though

```
= render :partial => "layouts/invoiceItem", :collection => p.invoices, :as => :i
```

Doesn't work.  Do I need to set up the nested iteration inside the controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like...

```
= render "layouts/allInvoices", :p => @projects
```

Then

```
- # layouts/allInvoices
- p.invoices.each do |invoice|
  = render "layouts/invoiceItem", :i => invoice

- # layouts/invoiceItem
= i.id   # this gives id of Invoice
```

Comment: I get nil for 'i' with this.  Same result as my attempted collection.  If I access 'i' directly, without rendering the partial, it works, though.

Comment: What is `invoice` in `layouts/allInvoices`

Comment: What are you asking?  In the construct 'p.invoices.each do |invoice|' "invoice" is a placeholder element for each iteration of p.invoices, where p is a placeholder for each iteration of Project.all and p.invoices is then each project's Invoice.all. e.g. Project.first.Invoice.first would be the first instance of "invoice"...but that has nothing really to do with my question.  I'm wondering how to pass the instance variable to a collection when the collection is itself called from a collection.